# Centering Navbar Tab Vertically in R Shiny

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny

```
ui <- shiny::bootstrapPage(
    
    shiny::tags$head(
        # Include custom CSS
        includeCSS("styles.css")
        
    ),
    
    
    shiny::navbarPage(
        
        title = "Test",
        collapsible = TRUE,
        theme       = shinythemes::shinytheme("flatly"),
        
        shiny::tabPanel(
            "Map"
        )
    )
    
    
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 80px;
}

.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  height: 80px;
}
```

How do I center the Map text vertically in the navigation tab? With the default theme, I get it to work, however, with the flatly theme I cannot get it centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the bootstrap css is not overwritten by the style sheet. In order to style the app, one has to use !important to make it work.

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 80px !important;
}

.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  height: 80px !important;
}
```